# Update notification every minute in the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to update a notification every 60 seconds by putting the thread to sleep in the loop.

```
for (int incr = 0; incr <= settingsPrefs.getInt("notifyMinutesBefore", 10); incr++) {

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wakeUpTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    if (settingsPrefs.getBoolean("runNotification" +i, true)) {

        notification.setContentText(""+timeUntilStartingInt);

        nm.notify(1000000 + i, notification.build());
        timeUntilStartingInt = timeUntilStartingInt - 1;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is, the notification doesn't gets updated if I manually turn on the phone's screen, as if `wakeLock.acquire()` is not working.

Is this the best way to update a notification every minute, and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off, to make this code work you'd need to acquire the wakelock before the phone goes to sleep-  basically outside the loop, and hold it until the loop is done.

Secondly, this isn't the right way to do it.  Use an alarm via AlarmManager with a WakefulBroadcastReceiver to update the notification and handle the wakelock for you.

Comment: And update the notification by updating the broadcast?

Comment: Update the notification from the Broadcast.

Comment: But instad of a loop inside the broadcast, calling the broadcast every 60s with `setRepeating()` ?